# large scale matrix multiplication and inverse solution

Tags: matrices

Suppose I have two very large matrix, but sparse (low rank), and one machine cannot hold all matrix data, I need to in a distributed way (e.g. Map-Reduce). Wondering if there are any exact solutions or approximate solutions?

The same for the question of inverse of a matrix, if one machine cannot hold all matrix data, I need to in a distributed way (e.g. Map-Reduce). Wondering if there are any exact solutions or approximate solutions?

Comment: If it has a low rank, it won't have an inverse.

Comment: @Paul, how about for multiply? Is there any solution for sparse exact/or approximate solution?

Comment: If you have a sparse invertible matrix, in general, its inverse will not be sparse. You could just search "matrix multiplication mapreduce" in google to get some implementations of this question.

Comment: @LinMa : In Matlab, you could probably use this : https://fr.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sparse.html. I believe that there are similar solutions in other languages.

Comment: @Batman, thanks for the information, do you have any approximate and faster matrix multiplication solutions for sparse matrix?

Comment: @jibounet, thanks for the reference. I am dealing big data and a single machine cannot host (like Matlab), wondering if you know any distributed approximate solution for matrix multiplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this method works. Think of a large matrix $A$ as another matrix
$$ A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
B & C\\
D & E
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Refer to each part $A,B,...$ as a 'submatrix'. Then your machine only has to multiply submatrices that are smaller in size. You can even define more submatrices so that your machine can do calculation. Finally you need to combine the result properly.  Choosing submatrices properly, you may also find inverse.

Comment: Thanks HR-Physics, wondering if you know any approximate matrix multiplication solution for sparse matrix?

Comment: BTW, mark your current reply as answer and grant bounty points, let us continue the discuss the remaining question.

Comment: @ Lin Ma, I often use multiplication of matrix by a dense vector, see this webpage : https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~scandal/cacm/node9.html

But I found another paper on the subject : Fast sparse matrix multiplication
Google this title. The method in the paper is rather hard but it's more effective.